# how to import PhotoSwipeLightbox in to nextjs 13.4 with typescript

Tags: typescript-typings, next.js13, photoswipe, import-module, typescript-module-resolution

I'm getting  error when I'm trying to import "PhotoSwipeLightbox" in nextjs component

I'm also installed PhotoSwipe Type packages with

```
npm i @types/photoswipe
```

when i import it like this

```
import PhotoSwipeLightbox from "photoswipe/lightbox";
```

i get this error in IDE

```
Cannot find module 'photoswipe/lightbox' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

and when i import it like this

```
import PhotoSwipeLightbox from "photoswipe/dist/types/lightbox/lightbox";
```

i get this error in browser

```
Module not found: Package path ./dist/types/lightbox/lightbox is not exported from package
```

also i try in tsconfig.json    `"moduleResolution": "Node",    "moduleResolution": "Node16",    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",`